# Crystal Report XI - Conditional Sum Issue

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I have a table with data called `InvoiceShipments`. It continues a row for each product shipped on an invoice. Each product belongs to a product category, which I can query and filter by. Some of the products are finished good products with a `Bill of Material`, where the `Bill of Materials` (BOM) is a list of the parts that combine to make the finished good.

In the `InvoiceShipments` table, the finished good is listed with a price but no cost. It is then followed by the components (BOM) of that finished good, which in turn have a cost but no price. I have a separate table that lists all of the component items and which finished goods it goes to. Note that component goods can belong to more than one BOM.

I can currently filter the `InvoiceShipments` by the products that I want based on the product category (from a join to a different table). What I want to do is grab that finished good number, and get a list of all the part #s that make up that BOM, then go back to the InvoiceShipments and sum the costs for all of the rows that match those component #s and invoice#. But I haven't been using Crystal long enough to know what to do at the query level, what to do with a command table, what to do with a formula, etc.

[Sample Screenshots:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gggCh.jpg)

Top table in the gallery is BOM table, second table is the `InvoiceShipments`, and the third is the desired outcome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you want to combine the invoice number but use the finished product information.  I've done something similar, solution is a little weird but it works.  You only need your InvoiceShipments table

1. Group by invoice number
2. Create a formula for Order ID, SKU and ProductName

   IF Price <> 0 AND Cost = 0 THEN
      Orider ID   '<-Change this according to the formula (SKU, ProductName)
   ELSE
      ""
3. Insert-> Summary on each of the formula as Maximum and place it on the grouped invoice line.
4. Since the Quantity is constant you can put that field on the grouped invoice line.
5. Insert-> Summary on Price then on Cost using SUM and place it on the grouped invoice line.
6. Hide the details.

This should give you the result you need.  What's happening is because your formula is only printing the finished goods information, the other items are blank.  So when you use MAXIMUM, the non-blank items will print.

Hope this helps.

---

NEW SOLUTION

I don't have any tables or views that is setup like your data so I can't test this solution, but hopefully there is enough info that you can formulate a good solution

I noticed that you can't use the materials in the InvoiceShipments to idenfity the Finished Product in BillofMaterials.  The Materials repeats itself.  We'll have to identify them using the finished product.

1. Add in InvoiceShipments and rename it InvoiceShipments1 (when adding tables, the right side windows, right click on the table and rename.
2. Using select expert, isolate your finished products. (Price <> 0 and Cost = 0)
3. Database -> Database Expert. Add in your BillofMaterials table.  Link SKU to ProductSKU.  Left Outer Join

Now the materials are associated with an invoice number, We can try and link another copy of the INvoiceShipments to the BOM.  This is tricky.

1. Database -> Database Expert. Add in your InvoiceShipments table rename to InvoiceShipments2.  Link InvoiceShipments2.invoice# to InvoiceShipments1.Invoice#, and InvoiceShipments2.SKU to Material#.  Use Left Outer Join
2. Create a formula that alternates between InvoiceShipments1 and InvoiceShipments2 on columns OrderID, SKU, and ProductName

   IF ISNULL({InvoiceShipments1.OrderID}) THEN
       {InvoiceShipments2.OrderID}
   ELSE
       {InvoiceShipments1.OrderID}
3. Create a formula combining InvoiceShipments2.invoice# and SKU (SKU formula version)
4. Group by formula in previous step (If the invoice contains 2 finished products, it will create 2 lines for one invoice.
5. On the GF put InvoiceShipments2.invoice#, OrderID (formula version), SKU (formula version), ProductNmae (formula version), InvoiceShipments2.quantity, Summerize(InvoiceShipments2.price), Summerize(InvoiceShipments2.cost)
6. Hide GH

Hope it works!

Comment: Sorry, I thought about it and it works well in my instance, but won't for yours if you have 2 finished products on the same invoice.  If I come up with something I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks. I have another option. I'm adding a new field called productCategory. The ProductCategory for the finished goods will have one name, and the ProductCategory for the component goods will be something different. So I'm thinking i can check each row to see if it in the finished good category, and then loop through the next row(s) and sum all the costs where the productCategory is the component goods, and return the sum to the original finished good row. I'm just not sure how to do that syntaxically in Crystal.